# Blender 2.79b Error when trying to Smart UV Project

Tags: texturing, uv

I try using `Smart UV Project` in Blender after selecting the whole mesh and going into edit mode, but I get the following error message which is totally inexplicable to me.

[image: Blender Error]

What should I do? I'm simply trying to texture a text logo.

Comment: You stated that you selected the whole mesh and then went into edit mode. Did you select the mesh after you changed to edit mode?

Comment: Yes. I do so by hitting the `a` hotkey. Not sure how else to specifically select the mesh while in edit mode, since the `selection` menu is different.

Comment: I've tried to recreate your issue by hiding part of the mesh, creating dangling (open?) edges, and by deleting all vertices in edit mode but I still receive no errors.

Comment: The exception raised on line 759 refers to oblist which is created at line 753 or 755 depending on certain characteristics. Someone smarter with the API would have to chime in. 753: oblist = [ob for ob in [context.active_object] if ob and ob.type == 'MESH']     755: oblist = [ob for ob in context.selected_editable_objects if ob and ob.type == 'MESH']